# How to validate the datatype of a variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

In Javascript, is there a way to check or validate the datatype of a variable?  I need to allow users to enter float values in the textbox.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you do a simple Google search before posting here? This has been asked and answered countless time on the web.

Comment: Sorry for asking this question.  Since I am a beginner in javascript I was not able to get a clear thing out there in google.  Anyway thank you stackoverflow.

Comment: I was going to +1 because it's a valid question, and then -1 for being lazy because the answer can be easily found in numerous resources. This is basic form validation that should come with your development environment of choice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're dealing with literal notation *only*, and not constructors, you can use [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/typeof_Operator):.

Example:

```
>var a = 1;
>var b = "asdasd";
>typeof(b);
"string"
>typeof(a);
"number"
```

### ---EDIT---

To validate numbers or float values use:

```
function isNumber (n) {
  return ! isNaN (n-0);
}
```

Example:

```
>var a = 1;
>isNumber(1);
True
```

Float Included, use `parsefloat`:

```
function isIntandFloat(n) {
   return typeof n === 'number' && parseFloat(n) == parseInt(n, 10) && !isNaN(n);
}
```

Or if you want just `float` use this:

```
function Float (n) {
  return n===+n && n!==(n|0);
}
```

Example:

```
>var a = 0.34324324324;
>Float(a);
true
>var int = 3;
>Float(int);
false
```

Comment: He doesn't actually mean the type. He wants users to enter just numbers, optionally with a decimal value.

Comment: for float value validation is there any similar function?

Comment: @user1671639 Yes, there is, I added it in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

A text box will always give you a `string` primitive value.

What you want is to see if the input can be converted from a `string` to a `number`. For this you can use `parseFloat()`.

```
var num = parseFloat(textbox.value);

if (isNaN(num)) {
    alert("Invalid input");
}
```

If you want more strict evaluation, use the `Number` function

```
var num = Number(textbox.value);

if (isNaN(num)) {
    alert("Invalid input");
}
```

Comment: Why not bind to key down and block letters?

Comment: But `parseFloat()` doesn't tell you if the entered value actually is a number, because `parseFloat("123abc")` returns `123`. @Jeroen - that doesn't prevent pasting and drag'n'drop of invalid values.

Comment: @nnnnnn: That's true, but it is convertible, providing a valid number. It depends on what OP wants to accept as input.

Comment: Why don't you use `+textbox.value`? It seems to fail on an input of "123abc" yet not need to create a `Number` object

Comment: @Ian: Yes, the unary `+` could be used too, but `Number` is a little clearer for a beginner. Using `Number` doesn't actually create an object. We still get the number primitive. It's only if `new` is used that we get the object wrapper. :-) http://es5.github.com/#x15.7.1

Comment: Very true on both of those. When I tested a small example between using `+` and `Number`, I had used `new` because I thought you had (didn't check first), so good point :)